# Storing the output of a for loop in a (block) diagonal matrix when the output of the for loop is 2*2 matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a “for loop” with 1000 iterations, where its output is a 2*2 matrix. So, my question is that “how can I store the output of all iteration as a diagonal (or block diagonal) matrix?”

```
X_t=[0 0.0016 0 0 -0.0015 0;0 0.0005 0 0 -0.0010 0];
X=[0 2 0 0 -1 0;0 0.5 0 0 -0.01 0];

ar = linspace(1e-3,1e2,1000);
w = 1i*ar;

M = zeros(2*numel(w));

for k=1:numel(w)

    P=[(10*exp(-w(k)))/(12*w(k)+1) (-8*exp(-3*w(k)))/(7*w(k)+1);      
       (5*exp(-8*w(k)))/(9*w(k)+1) (-17*exp(-4*w(k)))/(12*w(k)+1)];  

    W=[1 0;1/w(k) 0;w(k)/(1+0.3*w(k)) 0;0 1;0 1/w(k);0 w(k)/(1+0.3*w(k))];  

    Z=eye(2)+(X*W)*P;
    Y=((1.4)^2)*eye(2);
    Z_t=eye(2)+(X_t*W)*P;

    index = 2*k + [-1 0];
    M(index, index)=(Z'*Z_t)-(Y'*Y);

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should determine which indexes you want to change in each iteration:

```
index = 2*k + [-1 0];
M(index, index)=(Z'*Z_t)-(Y'*Y);
```

And to improve the performance, you should preallocate the output matrix:

```
M = zeros(2*numel(w));
```

Note that it may be more (memory) efficient to use a `sparse` matrix.

You can check if your matrix is correctly build using the `spy` command, which graphically displays the non zero matrix entries:

[image]
[image]